# Material UI Range Slider: Make the thumb snap to a value when its vicinity

Tags: reactjs, slider, material-ui

I need a slider having marks on fixed interval and one of those marks has to be the desired value.
whenever the thumb is in the vicinity of the desired value, **the thumb friction should snap it to this value**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved by controlling the value.
Refer the sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-pn84b?file=/demo.tsx